# iphone iOS5 how to render a draw a large UIView as PDF?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, pdf-generation

I'm trying to create a letter-sized report with iPhone. To do so, I created a large nib file and laid out all the report widgets I need in there.

Now I'm trying to convert the view into a PDF. Here's my **code, but it only draws the part of the view that is visible on the screen.**

I narrowed down the issue that on my test iPhone3GS, a 640x960 view's frame becomes 320x460 by the time viewWillAppear is called. If i reset the frame to 640x960 before saving a view as PDF, the file is displayed correctly. What may be causing the view's frame to be cut to the size of a visible rectangle? I know that for iPhone 3GS the view scale factor is 1, so it's not a scaling issue.

```
+(NSMutableData *)createPDFDatafromUIView:(UIView*)aView 
{
    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.frame, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData

    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    return pdfData;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I saw someone mention how to do this, sadly I can not find that source of information at this time. However, I think it might have been a matter of resizing the UIWindow to be the same dimensions as the view.